# All entries in Structure managed channel suddently closed and lost Structure data!

Tags: structure, status

Overnight a very unexpected and unexplained thing happened on my site. **I woke up this morning to find that all entries in a Structure managed channel had been "closed" and therefor all structure data for those entries had been lost.** I was lucky I had a developer who could revive them from a backup, otherwise it could have been a disaster that would have taken hours to fix.

Would the Structure module itself somehow be responsible for closing all of these entries? I don't think I did anything at all in Structure around the time this would have happened, but I can't think of what else might have caused this.

Are there any other add-ons that could do something like this?

It's a very scary and frustrating situation because I have no idea how it happened or how to prevent it from happening again. Would appreciate any advice on how I can find out the cause of this.

Comment: This happened again yesterday! All entries in one specific channel (which is manages by Structure) were suddenly and unexplainable closed and lost all Structure data. To the best of my knowledge I hadn't done anything at all in EE at the time this happened. Took me an hour to recreate all the Structure data. What could cause this?! This is the second time it's happened in about 5 weeks.

Comment: Even after updating to the latest version of Structure this is still occurring. Happened again today! So crippling to the site when it happens and I have absolutely no idea what's causing it. Has anyone other than myself encountered this issue?

Comment: This just happened to me... did you ever find out why it happens?

Comment: This was somehow caused by having a page created with an empty structure URL. Deleting the entry caused it to delete the whole structure tree, which in turn closed all the entry statuses. I'm not sure yet how is was possible to create the entry with no Structure URL, as it doesn't seem to be possible when manually creating an entry...!

Comment: That's a good insight James. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: For me, it happens when an entry is created using Channel Form (Safecracker).

Comment: And for me, it's happening on Channel Form EDIT not new entry creation. So it sounds like both new entries and editing entries can cause the problem.

Comment: This helps. We're on it and seeing fi this leads somewhere. Thanks!